# Conjecture on the solutions to the equation $J(x) = J(x+a)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, recreational-mathematics, divisor-sum

Propose $J(x)$, which is a function that takes in a number and outputs the sum of all its factors (including itself)

Firstly, I think it's pretty interesting as it allows you to describe certain types of numbers as solutions to different equations using this function. For example:

Perfect numbers are the solution to $J(x) = 2x$

Prime numbers are the solution to $J(x) = x+1$

But now to the problem that I need to ask you guys - as I sieved through data I saw that a lot of different inputs gave the same outputs, such as $J(6) = J(11)$ (they both equal 12)

I wondered what the difference between values that give the same output are, or in more mathematical language: $J(x+a) = J(x)$

I conjectured that for any integer $a$, there is at least one integer solution for $x$.

Some examples:

When $a$ is equal to $1$, a possible solution for $x$ is $14$

When $a$ is equal to $2$, a possible solution for $x$ is $33$

When $a$ is equal to $3$, a possible solution for $x$ is $382$

When $a$ is equal to $69$, a possible solution for $x$ is $8786$

So I guess my question to you guys is can you prove/disprove it?

Link to rudimentary python program for finding a specific gap value: 
https://repl.it/@JakubSkop/Factor-addition-function-gapvalues

Comment: The divisor function $\sigma(n)$ is very well studied.  See, e.g., [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html).  Not sure if anything in that link will be directly relevant, but it's a start.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A007365](https://oeis.org/A007365).

Comment: Also [A065932](https://oeis.org/A065932) and [A065933](https://oeis.org/A065933).  As with many conjectures in number theory, yours seems highly likely to be true, but proving it might be very difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's a start.  Let $S$ be the set of positive integers $a$ such that
$\sigma(x) = \sigma(x+a)$ has a solution.  Since $\sigma$ is multiplicative, 
if $\sigma(x) = \sigma(x+a)$ and $r$ is coprime to both $x$ and $x+a$, then
$\sigma(rx) = \sigma(r(x+a))$, so $ra \in S$.

Thus since $\sigma(14)=\sigma(15)$ for $a=1$, all $r$ coprime to $2, 3, 5$ and $7$ are in $S$.
That's a set of positive asymptotic density ($(1-1/2)\cdot(1-1/3)\cdot (1-1/5) \cdot (1-1/7) = 8/35$).

Since we know that $2,3, 5$ and $7$ are in $S$, all primes are in $S$.

Similarly, since $\sigma(54)=\sigma(56)$ for $a=2$, 
if $r$ is coprime to $2, 3, 7$ then $2r \in S$.

And since $\sigma(16) = \sigma(25)$ for $a=9$, if $r$ is coprime to $2$ and $5$ then $9r \in S$.

Comment: Oh, I see. And I'm guessing that if you were to continue this you would get every multiple of a prime, and at least prove it for a subset of the integers?